# PHP Sleep() Function Doesn't work

Tags: php, sleep, fopen, fread

This php code loops through a txt file to check if it includes some string. The txt file is provided by another application.

When I run this code I will get first the string of txt and after 60 seconds I get the same txt string. The file is ontinuously being written so the content should have changed.

**Why is same string being outputted every 60 seconds?**

```
ignore_user_abort();
set_time_limit(0);
$interval=60;
$flag=true;
file_put_contents("log.log","Starts \r\n");
while($flag){
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$mytime=date("y/m/d h:i:sa");   
$file = fopen("C:/work/testData/test.txt","r"); 
$myfile=fread($file,filesize("C:/work/testData/test.txt"));
if(stristr($myfile,"Finish writing tables")){
file_put_contents("log.log","Finished! Ready To Send Email $mytime       \r\n",FILE_APPEND);                                
$flag=false;    
}else{

file_put_contents("log.log","Still Running $mytime $myfile     \r\n",FILE_APPEND);          
}   

fclose($file);
sleep($interval);
}
```

Comment: What do you expect this code to do? The (vaguely) described behavior seems to match up with the code.

Comment: BTW, there's also file_get_contents() and you you should indent code that you expect others to read.

Comment: I want the code read test.txt every 60 seconds, once test.txt includes string "Finish writing tables". Test.txt file is updating its contents in the same time. And I find that in else {}, every 60 seconds it didnt read the updated test.txt file

Comment: clarified the text into paragraphs, removed unnecessary thanks